# Static google map image does not become fluid with media query

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I came across an issue that I haven't found an answer to after much googling. I have a basic website with a static google map (size 400x300) and I made the site responsive with media query at 600px.

```
<p>
<img id="karte" alt="Geolocation" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?&amp;size=400x300&amp;sensor=false&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;markers=color:green|label:B|Stuttgart&amp;markers=color:green|label:A|Hamburg">
</p>
```

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/bLahadgu/

When I reduce the screen to 600px, everything outside the image becomes fluid but the image only becomes fluid at 400px or lower.If I remove `size=400x300&amp;`that image doesn't appear at all. I checked the CSS code and it seems to be ok.

For normal screen size

```
img, #karte{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}
```

for small screen (inside the media query):

```
img, #karte{
   max-width: 100% !important;
   height: auto;
   float: none;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Have also made sure that the holder, content etc are also adjusted with smaller screen:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px){
    header, #content, #holder, section, nav, article, footer, .callout{
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        width: 100% ! important;
        float: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

I thought it might have been `<p>`but all become fluid at 600px just not the image. 
Is there something I am missing in my CSS code or it this how static images behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `width:100%` on #karte see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLahadgu/2/)

when you use

```
img,#karte { 
    max-width:100%!important;
}
```

the `#karte max-width` is the first width set, which is `400px`, that's why it won't stretch more than 400px;

so use this css below ( for media query )

```
img,
#karte {
max-width: 100% !important;
height: auto;
float: none;
margin: 0;
}
#karte {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width:none!important;
}
```

you should leave `max-width:100%` for the images so they don't stretch and look awkward, and then overwrite it for the map

Answer (score 2):

1st:
Remove "size=400x300" from tag

2nd:
Then write media queries

Comment: When I remove size then image does not appear

Comment: Add width and height from css like:
img{width:200px; height:300px;}

Comment: same occurs if I do this. I have it working with the solution above so I am happy thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `max-width` inside your media query for `width`, then your image map is going to be responsive.

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  img,
  #karte {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

For:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  img,
  #karte {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```